# getHeight() of view giving same result for portrait and landscape in Android

Tags: android, screen-orientation

For my application i am using accordian layout in which I have three panels and I am trying to set the panel(texview) sizes fit to the size of the device height.This doesn't work when there is a change in the screen orientation.My view size not changing according to the height of the device when it is in landscape.Please help me on this.

This is my code

```
if(layoutView.getId() == R.id.Advertitletext)
{
    openLayout = panel1;
    v = panel1.getVisibility();

    hideThemAll();
    if(v != View.VISIBLE)
    {
        panel1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        params = advertoutput.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = parentLinear.getHeight()-msgrecvtitle.getHeight()-msgsenttitle.getHeight()-mLogCheck.getHeight()-PearActivity.peartabs.getHeight();
        advertoutput.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

}
```

this is my onConfiguration() method

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        ViewTreeObserver observer = parentLinear.getViewTreeObserver();
        observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                parentLinear.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                if(openLayout==panel1){
                    params = advertoutput.getLayoutParams();
                    params.height = parentLinear.getHeight()-msgrecvtitle.getHeight()-msgsenttitle.getHeight()-mLogCheck.getHeight()-PearActivity.peartabs.getHeight();
                    advertoutput.setLayoutParams(params);
                }
                else if(openLayout == panel2){
                    params = msgrecvoutput.getLayoutParams();
                    params.height = parentLinear.getHeight()-adverttitle.getHeight()-msgsenttitle.getHeight()-mLogCheck.getHeight()-PearActivity.peartabs.getHeight();
                    msgrecvoutput.setLayoutParams(params);

                }else   if(openLayout == panel3){
                    params = msgsentoutput.getLayoutParams();
                    params.height = parentLinear.getHeight()-adverttitle.getHeight()-msgrecvtitle.getHeight()-mLogCheck.getHeight()-PearActivity.peartabs.getHeight();
                    msgsentoutput.setLayoutParams(params);
                }

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Is this code inside onCreate?

Comment: ya this is inside onCreate() like this three views are there in else loop.Inside configurationChanged() method it is giving the previous orientations's height and not the latest one

Answer (score 1):

If you include in your `AndroidManifest` file that you need system to handle orientation changes:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

You should implement your code inside `onConfigurationChanged()`, else it should be inside `onResume()` (as the activity is paused then resumed and onCreate is not called again.

Comment: ya i have wrote the same code in onConfigurationChanged() also but I am getting the old value.

Comment: Are you sure you added android:configChanges="orientation" in your Manifest file?

Comment: It seems you did not add the code part where you retreive `parentLinear`, `msgrecvtitle`, `msgsenttitle`, `mLogCheck` and `PearActivity.peartabs` in `onConfigurationChanged()` (i.e. you are using old values from `onCreate()`

Comment: parentLinear is still created outside onConfigurationChanged(). and my guess is that parentLinear.getHeight() will retreive the old values. Try to reinitialize parentLinear inside onConfigurationChanged()

Comment: ya thanks for your suggestion,but no luck only for landscape i am not able to calculate exact height,when i change back to portrait it works fine.

Comment: Hi @AndroidCrazy have you solved the problem?I am also facing the same problem. Please post your comments if you have solved the problem.Thanks in advance.